# Get child function name in parent function method

Tags: javascript

Function B extends A, How to get B function name in parent function A, when I call `parentMethod()` on object of B child function object.

```
function A() {

    this.parentMethod = function() {
         //alert('display B function name');
    }
}

function B() {


}


B.prototype = new A();

var b = new B();  
b.parentMethod();
```

Comment: Functions don't have names. A function declaration creates a variable that references the created function object. Any number of variables can reference the same function object, some can have no reference ('name') at all. So what is its name?

Comment: What do you want to get? B doesn't have any methods. How would the parent know anything about the child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest Way to do this is:

```
function A() {

    this.parentMethod = function() {
         alert(this.constructor.name);
    }
}

function B() {

}


B.prototype = new A();  
B.prototype.constructor = B; //Add this line.

var b = new B();  
b.parentMethod();
```

Now when you call parentMethod it will display B as a constructor name.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the `constructor` property to point to the correct function (i.e. `B`)

```
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

Then you can access the name of the constructor function via

```
this.parentMethod = function() {
     alert(this.constructor.name);
}
```

Note though that [`Function.name` is a **non-standard** property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) and might not work in all browsers. The alternative would be to hardcode the function name by overriding `parentMethod` or adding a property to the instance with the function name. You could also just use the function reference (`this.constructor`) directly, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

---

A better way to setup inheritance is to use [`Object.create` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and call the parent constructor function in the child constructor function:

```
function A() {}

A.prototype.parentMethod = function() {};


function B() {
    A.call(this); // call parent constructor
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype); // establish inheritance
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

Comment: You could also do: `B.prototype.constructorName = 'B';` which is about as useful.